# Using string length defined in the matched string

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

Having the following string:

```
commit a8c11fcee68881dfb86095aa36290fb304047cf1
log size 110
Author: XXXXXX XXXXXXXX <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX>
Date:   Tue, 10 Apr 2012 11:19:44 +0300

    First commit

3       0       README.MD
```

How can I use the value `110` in the definition of the grammar to match the rest of the things? The "log size" includes the fields (here: `Author` and `Date`, but there could be any number of fields) and the actual message.

The last line is not part of the "log message".

What I want to get are the values of `commit`, the dictionary with metadata like `Author` and `Date`, and the actual log message, here "First commit".

The thing is, `log size` tells me how long this message is, but this includes the fields `Author` and `Date` as well.

`110` being the size of this string:

```
Author: XXXXXX XXXXXXXX <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX>
Date:   Tue, 10 Apr 2012 11:19:44 +0300

    First commit
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. You've got the file. Is there some desired output you're trying to get to?

Comment: @Flavius What are the values of commit ? The data in the line ``3       0       README.MD`` or the dictionnary contained in the first lines of the log message ?

Comment: @eyquem the output is the result of `git log --reverse --date-order -p --date=rfc --log-size --boundary --full-history --numstat --dirstat -z --no-abbrev-commit -M --full-index -t`

Comment: @Flavius I think my question was stupid. The commit values are in the string ``a8c11fcee68881dfb86095aa36290fb304047cf1`` , aren't they ? - I don't know to interpret the long instruction you gave

Comment: @Flavius There are 52 characters in the line ``'Author...'``, 40 in the line ``'Date...'`` and 13 in the line ``'First commit\n'`` , comprised the LF characters ``\n``. The total of characters is 105, not 110. Even if there were ``\r\n`` at the end of lines, it would do 108 characters

Comment: Trust me, the number is right :-)

Comment: @Flavius I trust you. I have a problem of display, I don't see the blank line between the 'Date' line and the 'First commit' line. But having read the message of NPE , I saw there's one in fact.

Comment: @Flavius See my answer please. By the way, do the code and the result part appear correctly indented to you ? I see them non indented on my display

Comment: @Flavius. Thank you. By the way, now I see my code and result  indented , I understand nothing

Comment: @Flavius I've made little improvements of writing, not on algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same idea of algorithm as NPE.
But I pushed the use of regexes a litlle farther.

I 've extended the analyzed text with a second occurence of log message, taking care to put the right number of characters in the 'log size xxx\n' line

**regex1** cuts each occurence in 4 groups. The third group contains the lines having the dictionary and the fourth group has the trailing lines after the dictionary-lines and before the other occurence.

```
import re

ss = """commit a8c11fcee68881dfb86095aa36290fb304047cf1
log size 110
Author: XXXXXX XXXXXXXX <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX>
Date:   Tue, 10 Apr 2012 11:19:44 +0300

    First commit
3       0       README.MD
blablah bla
commit 12458777AFDRE1254
log size 170
   Author: Jim Bluefish <jimblfsh@gmail.com>
Date   :   Yesterday 21:45:01 +0800
  A key with whitespace :       A_stupid_value    

    Funny commit
  From far from you
457      popo       not_README.MD"""

n = 0
print ('------ DISPLAY OF THE TEXT ------\n'
       ' col 1: index of line,\n'
       ' col 2: number of chars in the line\n'
       ' col 3: total of the numbers of chars of lines\n'
       ' col 4: repr(line)\n')
for j,line in enumerate(ss.splitlines(1)):
    n += len(line)
    print '%2d  %2d  %3d  %r' % (j,len(line),n,line)


print '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-='
print '\n\n\n------ ANALYSER 2 OF THE TEXT ------'

regx1 = re.compile('^commit +(.+) *\r?\n'
                   'log size +(\d+) *\r?\n'
                   '((?:^ *.+?(?<! ) *: *.+(?<! ) *\r?\n)+)'
                   '((?:.*\r?\n(?!commit))+)',
                   re.MULTILINE)

regx2 = re.compile('^ *(.+?)(?<! ) *: *(.+)(?<! ) *\r?\n',
                   re.MULTILINE)

for mat in regx1.finditer(ss):

    commit_value,logsize,dicolines,msg = mat.groups()

    print ('\ncommit_value == %s\n'
           'logsize == %s'
           % (commit_value,logsize))

    print 'dictionary :\n',dict(regx2.findall(dicolines))

    actual_log_message = msg[0:int(logsize)-len(dicolines)].strip(' \r\n')
    print 'actual_log_message ==',repr(actual_log_message)
```

result

```
------ DISPLAY OF THE TEXT ------
 col 1: index of line,
 col 2: number of chars in the line
 col 3: total of the numbers of chars of lines
 col 4: repr(line)

 0  48   48  'commit a8c11fcee68881dfb86095aa36290fb304047cf1\n'
 1  13   61  'log size 110\n'
 2  52  113  'Author: XXXXXX XXXXXXXX <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX>\n'
 3  40  153  'Date:   Tue, 10 Apr 2012 11:19:44 +0300\n'
 4   1  154  '\n'
 5  17  171  '    First commit\n'
 6  26  197  '3       0       README.MD\n'
 7  12  209  'blablah bla\n'
 8  25  234  'commit 12458777AFDRE1254\n'
 9  13  247  'log size 170\n'
10  45  292  '   Author: Jim Bluefish <jimblfsh@gmail.com>\n'
11  36  328  'Date   :   Yesterday 21:45:01 +0800\n'
12  51  379  '  A key with whitespace :       A_stupid_value    \n'
13   1  380  '\n'
14  17  397  '    Funny commit\n'
15  20  417  '  From far from you\n'
16  33  450  '457      popo       not_README.MD'



------ ANALYSER OF THE TEXT ------

commit_value == a8c11fcee68881dfb86095aa36290fb304047cf1
logsize == 110
dico :
{'Date': 'Tue, 10 Apr 2012 11:19:44 +0300', 'Author': 'XXXXXX XXXXXXXX <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX>'}
actual_log_message == 'First commit'


commit_value == 12458777AFDRE1254
logsize == 170
dico :
{'Date': 'Yesterday 21:45:01 +0800', 'A key with whitespace': 'A_stupid_value', 'Author': 'Jim Bluefish <jimblfsh@gmail.com>'}
actual_log_message == 'Funny commit\n  From far from you'
```

Comment: @Flavius I had seen, I was just wondering who. Thank you. - Note that the use of regexes is sensitive to the slightest variation in the analyzed text and that result can become incorrect if the variation has not been anticipated. If you have possibility to write additional controls on the result, as a number of expected occurences, it would be canny. Or not necessary if the analyzed has a strong formatting

Comment: I've went the regex way long ago. I've accepted your answer just because you've put more effort into it. Hopefully it will help someone else.

Comment: @Flavius I'm thinking about your problem. Why do you want to use the log size value written in the text, in fact ? First , are there really several occurences of a log message in your text (as I supposed in my answer) ? And second, if yes, aren't the limits between occurences of log messages of a relatively stable type that could be catched by regex ? Abd the lines after the actual log message part, what are they , aren't they of a certain pattern ? - I will try to propose another code .

Comment: Log messages cannot be caught by the deterministic regexes, without the log size. They have no format, no terminals to mark the end syntactically.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in three stages:

1. Use a regex to find each commit, and get its id and log size.
2. Using the end of the match in step 1 and the log size, I'd slice the metadata+message out of the string.
3. Parse the string from step 2 into a dictionary+message.

The first two steps can be done as follows:

```
In [25]: s = """commit a8c11fcee68881dfb86095aa36290fb304047cf1
log size 110
Author: XXXXXX XXXXXXXX <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX>
Date:   Tue, 10 Apr 2012 11:19:44 +0300

    First commit
3       0       README.MD
"""

In [26]: m = re.search('commit (.*)\nlog size (.*)\n', s)

In [27]: s[m.end():m.end()+int(m.group(2))]
Out[27]: 'Author: XXXXXX XXXXXXXX <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX>\nDate:   Tue, 10 Apr 2012 11:19:44 +0300\n\n    First commit\n'
```

If the last string is called `step2`, you can do the rest of the parsing as follows:

```
In [48]: meta, msg = step2.split('\n\n', 1)

In [49]: dict([map(str.strip, line.split(':', 1)) for line in meta.split('\n')])
Out[49]: 
{'Author': 'XXXXXX XXXXXXXX <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX>',
 'Date': 'Tue, 10 Apr 2012 11:19:44 +0300'}

In [50]: msg
Out[50]: '    First commit\n'
```

Comment: Is there no elegant way of doing it in only one step?

Comment: The format is messy, so I don't expect there to be an elegant method of parsing it. I could of course be proved wrong on this.

Comment: In general, there is no elegant way to do this, because this is a context-sensitive language. You have to change your parser as you go: in this case, you change the number of characters eaten by the log parser.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question with the "pyparsing" tag, so here is how you might use pyparsing to address it. Pyparsing includes a helper method called `countedArray` that does pretty much what you want. You can think of:

```
countedArray(something)
```

as a short-cut for:

```
integer + something*(whatever was parsed as the integer)
```

and will return the parsed data as the list of somethings.

```
source = """commit a8c11fcee68881dfb86095aa36290fb304047cf1
log size 110
Author: XXXXXX XXXXXXXX <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX>
Date:   Tue, 10 Apr 2012 11:19:44 +0300

    First commit<not in the message, more than 110 chars>

3       0       README.MD
"""

from pyparsing import *
any_char = Word(printables+" \n",exact=1).leaveWhitespace()

log_message = countedArray(any_char)
# we want a string, not an array of single characters
log_message.setParseAction(lambda t: ''.join(t[0]))

entry = "commit" + Word(hexnums)('id') + "log size" + log_message

msg = entry.parseString(source)[-1]
print (msg)
```

Gives:

```
Author: XXXXXX XXXXXXXX <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX>
Date:   Tue, 10 Apr 2012 11:19:44 +0300

    First commit
```

and you can see that we have read up to, but not including, the "not in the message..." part (which I added to your source string to show that `countedArray` correctly stops at the 110th character). I added a parse action, which pyparsing will run as a parse-time callback when the expression is matched. The matched tokens are passed to the parse action, and if the action returns a value, that value replaces the parsed tokens in the output. Here we use a simple lambda to take the first token (the array of characters), and join them into a single string.

But you also said that you wanted to extract the fields 'Author' and 'Date'. They are actually part of the stuff that was extracted in the log_message, so you'll have to pass that string to another expression. Fortunately, you can do that kind of thing in a second parse action.

In this second-phase parsing, I've decided to create a parser that will take any keyed values of the form:

```
some key: the value of that key up to the end of the line
```

in case 'Author' and 'Date' are just examples of any number of keys that you might find in your source text. Pyparsing also has named results, similar to named groups in regular expressions. Normally when the names are known, you can just tack on the name as shown above with your commit id. But in your log message, the actual names are parsed out of the input itself, so for this, pyparsing has a `Dict` class. The `Dict` class will take a parsed set of groups, and decorate that data with names for each group, taking the first element of the group as the name, and the remainder of the group as the value. So we want names for each keyed value shown, where everything up to the ':' is going to be the name, skip over the colon and any leading spaces, and then take the rest of the line as the value.

```
COLON = Suppress(':')
keyed_value = Group(Word(printables+' ',excludeChars=':') + COLON + empty + restOfLine)
keyed_entries = Dict(ZeroOrMore(keyed_value))
```

We still want that log message too, easiest to use a pyparsing `SkipTo` to just take everything else up to the end of the string:

```
everything_else_up_to_the_end_of_the_string = SkipTo(StringEnd())
```

Here is the grammar for your log message body:

```
log_message_body = keyed_entries + 
                    everything_else_up_to_the_end_of_the_string('message')
```

We already have a parse action to combine all the parsed characters in the log_message into a single string, but it is possible to chain multiple parse actions onto a single expression. We'll add a second parse action, which will parse the parsed log_message using the log_message_body grammar:

```
def parseMessage(tokens):
    return log_message_body.parseString(tokens[0])
log_message.addParseAction(parseMessage)
```

Now we can run our full parser again, and this time, dump out the results and their names. The named results can be accessed just as if they were attributes of an object (or you can use dict notation if you prefer):

```
log_entry = entry.parseString(source)
print (log_entry.id)
print (log_entry['message'])
print (log_entry.dump())
```

Gives:

```
a8c11fcee68881dfb86095aa36290fb304047cf1
First commit
['commit', 'a8c11fcee68881dfb86095aa36290fb304047cf1', '
    log size', ['Author', 'XXXXXX XXXXXXXX <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX>'], 
    ['Date', 'Tue, 10 Apr 2012 11:19:44 +0300'], 
    'First commit']
- Author: XXXXXX XXXXXXXX <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX>
- Date: Tue, 10 Apr 2012 11:19:44 +0300
- id: a8c11fcee68881dfb86095aa36290fb304047cf1
- message: First commit
```